# How to improve efficiency with Camel?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel, esper

I have a problem of efficiency in my project which uses Camel with the [Esper component](http://camel.apache.org/esper.html).

I have several external datasources feeding information to camel endpoints. Each Camel endpoint that receives data transfers it to a route that processes it and then delivers it at an Esper endpoint.

The image below illustrates this behavior:

[image: problem]

The efficiency problem is that all of this is done by a single Java thread. Thus if I have many sources, there is a huge bottleneck.

The following code accurately illustrates what is going on with the image:

```
public final void configure() throws OperationNotSupportedException{
    RouteDefinition route = from("xmpp://localhost:5222/?blablabla...");

    // apply some filter
    FilterDefinition filterDefinition = route.filter().method(...);

    // apply main processor
    ExpressionNode expressionNode = filterDefinition.process(...);


    // set destination
    expressionNode = filterDefinition.to("esper://session_X");
}
```

**To fix this problem, I have to handle this situation with a pool of threads or using some sort of parallel processing.** I cannot use patterns like multicast, recipient list, etc because all of those send the same message to multiple endpoints / clients, which is not the case in my examples.

A possible solution would be having 1 thread per each "Datasource endpoint -> Route -> Esper endpoint" combination, like the image bellow:

[image: solution_1]

Another possible solution is to have 1 thread receive everything from the datasources, and then dispatch it to multiple threads handling the route processing together with the other endpoint:

[image: solution_2]

**PS:** I am open to any other possible suggestions you may have.

To achieve one of these I have considered using the Camel [SEDA component](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) component, however, this one does not seem to allow me to have dynamic thread pools, because the `concurrentConsumers` property is static. Furthermore, I am not sure if I can use a SEDA endpoint at all, because I believe (although I am not completely sure) that the syntax for an endpoint like `.to("seda:esper://session_X?concurrentConsumers=10")` is invalid for Camel.

So, at this point I am quite lost and I don't know what to do:
- Is SEDA the solution I am looking for?
- If yes, how do I integrate it with the Esper endpoint given the syntax problem?
- Are there any other solutions / Camel components that could fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a separate `seda` route that is distributing your message to the esper engine such as (using the fluent style):

```
public final void configure() throws OperationNotSupportedException{
    from("xmpp://localhost:5222/?blablabla...")
        .filter().method(...)
        .process(...)
        .to("seda:sub");

    from("seda:sub?concurrentConsumers=10)
     .to("esper://session_X");
 }
```

That said, `seda` should only be used if loosing messages is not a problem. Otherwise you should use a more robust protocol such as `jms` that allows to persist messages.

**EDIT:**

Beside `seda`, you could use `threads()`, where you could customize the threading behaviour by defining an `ExecutorService`:

```
public final void configure() throws OperationNotSupportedException{
    from("xmpp://localhost:5222/?blablabla...")
        .filter().method(...)
        .process(...)
        .threads()
        .executorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
        .to("esper://session_X");
 }
```

If you using `seda` or `threads()`, you may loose transaction safety in case of failures. For this case or if you need to balance the workload to several remote hosts, you may use `jms`. More information about this solution is found [here](http://camel.apache.org/jms).

Comment: Oh boy, Thanks! kudos++.
However I have more questions. Since it is better to use a thread pool, is there a way to do it with the SEDA component? And what about loosing messages? Can you be more specific? :S